# Python - PING a list of IP Address from database

Tags: python, database, networking

## Python - PING a list of IP Address from database

I have a list of ip addresses consisting of 200 locations, which in that location there are 4 ip addresses that I need to do ping testing. I intend to make a command which when I write the name or code of a particular location then it will directly ping to 4 ip address at that location. I have learned a bit to create a list that contains the ip address I entered through the command input () like this :

```
import os
import socket

ip = []
y = ['IP 1 : ','IP 2 : ', 'IP 3 : ', 'IP 4 : ']

while True:
       for x in y:
             server_ip = input(x)
             ip.append(server_ip)
       break

for x in ip:
       print("\n")
       rep = os.system('ping ' + x + " -c 3")
```

please give me a little advice about the command I want to make so that I no longer need to enter the ip address one by one. which still makes me confused, especially on how to make the existing items in the database into a variable x which we will insert into this command;
rep = os.system ('ping' + x + "-c 3")

Comment: What exactly do you want to do instead of entering the IP addresses one by one? What should the input be—or, if it's not `input()`, where else do you expect your script to find its input?

Comment: Sorry, in the command above i need to input the IP one by one because i don't have a list or dict that contains the IP. Now i have an excel file that contains list of location with its IP Addresses and i want to make that the command is only input location code and then automatically ping to all existing ip according to the location code that I enter. Sorry if my question is confusing, i just learned it and hard enough to find tutorial in my language

Comment: OK, so you want to take a filename as `input()` or `sys.argv[1]`, then read an Excel file at that location? There are Python libraries for reading Excel files, but they're a bit complicated. If you can tell Excel to export the file as a .CSV instead, you can use [the `csv` module that comes with Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), which includes some nice example code in the docs.

Comment: So, i need to learn about csv module first, right? OK, thank you so much sir.

Comment: The `csv` module isn't the _only_ way to do this, but it is probably the simplest—and it's definitely worth learning the basics of it at some point, and not hard to learn, so why not now? :)

Comment: As a beginner sometimes it is difficult to decide where to start. Thank you very much for the advice sir. I really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: It now iterates over a CSV file rather than a hard-coded Python dictionary.**

I believe you will be better off using [python dictionaries](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) rather than python lists. Assuming you are using **Python 3.X**, this is what you want to run:

```
import os
import csv

# Save the IPs you want to ping inside YOURFILE.csv
# Then iterate over the CSV rows using a For Loop
# Ensure your ip addresses are under a column titled ip_address
with open('YOURFILE.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        rep = os.system("ping " + row['ip_address'] + " -c 3")
```

Comment: I have 200 items that each item has 4 IP addresses, is it okay if I put them all in the dictionary? or better I use database?

Comment: OK - 200*4 strings is not something you want to hard-code. (It would not be very maintainable). But it is also not so big that it needs a database. I have just read your answers above - Iterating over values coming from a CSV file sounds like the best match for your issue.

Comment: Ok sir, Thank you very much. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I have edited my response so that it uses a CSV file instead of a dictionary.